# Smart way to check the property $ab=0\implies a=0$ or $b=0$ to form an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, integration, ring-theory

Is there a smart way to check if something satisfies the rule $ab=0\implies a=0$ or $b=0$ to show its an integral domain.

I am looking at $\{a+b\sqrt{2}:a,b\in \Bbb Z\}$ and $\{a+b\sqrt{2}:a,b\in \Bbb Q\}$ and trying to see if they are integral domains, and it occurred to me that I am bad at this, really bad.

So what I tried to do was take $(a+b\sqrt{2})(c+d\sqrt{2})=ac+bc\sqrt{2}+ad\sqrt{2}+2bd=0$

and I sit there and try to see how I can get this product to equal zero, without $(a+b\sqrt{2})$ or $(c+d\sqrt{2})$ to be equal to zero.

What is the smart mathematically experienced way to check that sort of thing?

Comment: Since $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$, the equality is equivalent to $ac + 2bd = 0$ and $ad + bc = 0$.

Comment: We need to show closure under addition and multiplication. The $xy=0$ implies $x=0$ or $y=0$, and all the other properties, are inherited from the fact our numbers are all real numbers (or if you prefer, complex numbers), and that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: You are also allowed to assume that $a, b, c, d$ are all integers with $\gcd(a, b, c, d) = 1$.

Comment: Try taking norms.  $|a+b\sqrt 2|=a^2-2b^2$ is only $0$ trivially.  And norm is multiplicative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see that $\{a+b\sqrt{2}\;|\; a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is a ring, you can check that it's a subring of $\mathbb{R}$ (show closure under subtraction and multiplication - also clearly $1$ belongs to this subring).

An integral domain is a commutative ring with $1$, $1 \not= 0$, and no zero divisors.

Once we know that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is a subring of $\mathbb{R}$, we know that $1 \not=0$ and it is commutative (since these things are true in $\mathbb{R}$).

This only leaves us to check that there are no zero divisors. But this too is a property inherited from $\mathbb{R}$. Notice that a zero divisor in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ would be a zero divisor in $\mathbb{R}$. But $\mathbb{R}$ has no zero divisors (it's a field) so neither can your ring.

In general, a (non-zero) subring (with $1$) of an integral domain is itself an integral domain.

If you want to check for zero divisors directly, you can: $(a+b\sqrt{2})(c+d\sqrt{2}) = (ac+bd2)+(ad+bc)\sqrt{2}=0$ forces $ac+bd2=0$ and $ad+bc=0$. 
Without loss of generality, suppose $a+b\sqrt{2} \not=0$.

Case 1: $a\not=0$ then $d=-bc/a$ so $0=ac+2bd=ac+2b(-bc/a)$ so that $a^2c=2b^2c$. This is impossible unless $c=0$ (use prime factorizations to see that the right hand side has even/odd power of $2$ then left hand side has odd/even power of $2$). Now $c=0$, so $0=ad+b(0)=ad$ so $d=0$ since $a\not=0$. Therefore, we must have $c+d\sqrt{2}=0$.

Case 2: $a=0$ and since $a+b\sqrt{2} \not=0$ we must have $b \not=0$. Thus $0c+2db=0$ and $0d+bc=0$. But $b \not=0$ so $d=0$ and $c=0$. Again $c+d\sqrt{2}=0$.

No zero divisors!

Comment: That was really clear, and definitely smart, thanks so much, this will help me a heap in the future.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. :)